# Get just the filenames of changed files from svn command

Tags: svn

Hopefully a simple flag that I'm missing, I've got that

```
svn diff -r 321:322
```

Will return the diff of two revisions, is there an easy way to produce a list of just the names of the files affected, so I have a list of files to roll out, rather than filtering through the diff output for the filenames.

If I could get the filenames with the full path to them that would be ideal, but I may be asking too much.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in *nix you could do

```
svn diff --summarize -r 321:322 | colrm 1 8
```

That will give you the full path from your project root directory

Comment: isn't that that the current status though. I just want the filenames that have changed between two revisions.

Comment: This will just show all changed files, so if you have Deleted files they'll also be in the list, but you won't know the state (A,M,D)

Comment: it gets the filename. colrm removes the first 8 columns of the output, which is the status.

Comment: ah, I see what you mean, you want all differences between the two revisions. sorry about that, I'll edit.

Comment: cool thanks, how do I do this between two revisions not between my working copy and the head of the repo though

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was after. A nice list of files to rollout and locations to roll 'em out to :)